# How to get the element reference "this" in EmberJS events?

Tags: ember.js

I want to access the target element in the called method in onchange. I have the following code:

**Template**

```
<select class="form-control" data-abc="1" onchange={{action 'someMethod' value="target.value"}} >
  <option value="">Select</option>
  .
  .
  .
</select>
```

**Component**

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    actions: {
      someMethod(value) {
        jQuery(this).data("abc"); // <-- Want to access element here
      }
    }
});
```

But, this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `value="target.value"`, `someMethod` will receive only the value alone and it will not receive default `event` object.

```
onchange={{action 'someMethod'}}
```

your component code would be,

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    actions: {
      someMethod(event) {
        //its event object, you can access event.target to get element or event.target.value to get the value.
      }
    }
})
```

Comment: I don't need event but element reference to access data attribute.

Comment: that's what I tried to convey it in `someMethod` code comments. Any how I am glad you got it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer:

```
<select class="form-control" data-abc="1" onchange={{action 'someMethod' value="target"}} >
  <option value="">Select</option>
  .
  .
  .
</select>
```

As can be seen in above code, we can pass the **target** instead of **target.value**. Then wrap target in jQuery to access desired data attribute.

Comment: If we mentioned, `value` parameter then what it will do, it will get this property from the first argument passed to that method, in our case, it's `event`, so it will destructure `target` property from `event` object.

Comment: You will like this article http://miguelcamba.com/blog/2016/01/24/ember-closure-actions-in-depth/  in this `Extracting values out of the first argument` part it's very well explained

Comment: @kumkanillam Thank you for the article. I upvoted. Can you please answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44651831/access-array-element-in-ember-template