# Access array element in ember template

Tags: ember.js

I have already tried this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044219/how-do-i-access-an-access-array-item-by-index-in-handlebars)

But, i want to achieve the following:

**Component**

```
abc = [10,20,30,40,50]
cde = [0,1,2,3,4]
```

**Template**

```
{{#each cde as |num|}}
  {{ abc.[num] }}
{{/each}}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
10 20 30 40 50
```

But, it doesn't output anything. What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
{{#each cde as |num|}}
  {{get abc (concat num '')}}
{{/each}}
```

I dont get the need for `cde` array,
`each` block comes with index, if needed you can use it.

```
{{#each abc as |num index|}}
```